# How to load files by number of iterator in python?

Tags: python-3.x, file, cycle

I have files with names

```
file140.000
file140.400
file140.800
....
```

How to load these file with a cycle?

```
for i in np.arange (140,160,0.4):
    x, y, a, b = np.loadtxt('file"$i"', unpack=True, usecols=[0, 2, 3, 4])
```

There is a mistake in

```
file"$i"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use `'file'+str(i)` instead?

Comment: Thank you very much and how to save the file? I tried: `plt.savefig('maps_omega_'+str("%0.1f" % i))` or `plt.savefig('maps_omega_{"%0.1f" % i}')`

Comment: Yes, you can always cross check using a print command `print('maps_omega_'+str("%0.1f"%i))`

Comment: .png missed, but the file's name is `maps_omega_{"%0.1f" % i}.png` there is no number instead of `{"%0.1f" % i}`. When I use `print('maps_omega_'+str("%0.1f"%i))` I get correct name in console - with number.

Comment: Is there any log that you see? Can you cross check if `plt.savefig("maps_omega_"+str("%0.1f"%i)+".png")` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have used to include the variable in the string is not correct.

There are multiple ways of doing it, if you are using python 3.6 or newer you can use f-strings, which follow the  `f'string{variable}'` syntax.

In your case, that would be `f'file{i}'`.